# how do I make sure that click events for overlayed images hit the intended target in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, click

I have two images on a WPF window that are on top of each other. Both images are visible with transparency to result in the appearance of one image.

Both images are square and the same size.

What I need to achieve is that any mouse clicks that land on the top image actually fire the click event in the rear image.

I appreciate that the obvious answer is code for the top image, however, there are scenarios where the top image wont be over the bottom image and therefore I am trying to make the application behave as if the top image is not there at all (and therefore all clicks must land on the bottom image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) to false on the top image.

Or both images can listen to the same click event via Routed events.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

More specifically, use the "Tunneling" strategy . That way, you can put the click logic for both images in the same place.

Comment: great answer, but for this scenario I will use isHittest, thanks the information also made me think slightly differently about functions and events.